# Add to internal storage using external storage

Tags: partitioning, wine, sd-card, storage

ok, I'm a pretty big Windows nut, no clue what I'm doing with Linux. Google normally is helpful, but I'm finding myself at a loss here.

see I've got myself a Intel Compute Stick running Ubuntu 14.04.6 Trusty Tahr, and I want to run old Windows 98/XP games on it, if possible.

my problem is I go to install WINE and all that, but the internal drive gets completely full, and that makes the device basically stop working. so I reboot, and when I enter my password to login, I just get a blank screen. so I've had to factory reset the thing 3 times now, hitting esc at bootup and telling it to reinstall the OS.

what's super annoying is this thing is supposed to have 8GB, and I thought that'd be plenty, but alas, I was mistaken.

so I'd like to tell Linux to use the free space on an external SD card (I've got a 4GB in there right now, but I've ordered a 16GB to take it's place) and combine that storage with the storage it's using to install updates and WINE. I'd like it to download toglamorus the SD card by default.

I'm not planning to do anything glamorous with this thing, just super old games, and if it runs those well, then I might toy around with Steam and install Plants Vs Zombies or something. I just need the extra space to try things out. I don't want to keep factory resetting every time something doesn't work. I'm basically using this thing as a test, so I can dink around with Linux and see if I want to use it more in the future.

oh also, I Googled how to toy with the partitions, but Google says I need to use the install CD. but my compute stick came with Ubuntu preinstalled, and I'd rather not mess with the OS, because with my experience so far, I'd probably brick my device. so if I can use the SD card rather than mess with the internal drive, that'd be great. if I mess up the SD card, I can fix that with Windows.

Comment: If your $HOME (user directory) has insufficient space to create needed gui work files (created at login), a GUI login cannot proceed, thus when you fill up the space, this could be what's causing you to reset back to defaults your device (all you need to do is login via a terminal, free some space and it'll work again).  I suspect shadowing a 'mount` (your additional storage) over an existing directory is what I'd do, but I don't know compute sticks (how their Ubuntu differs).  also fyi: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (2014.April release) reaches the end of it's 5 year free support very soon.

Comment: ok, how do I go about shadowing the mount?

Comment: If you have a directory /dir on your system, then you later `mount blah:/blah /dir` then whatever was in the old /mnt is hidden (shadowed) by whatever is in the mounted directory.  This can 'scare' new users as they often expect it would combine the directories; but their own files (stored in /dir are just shadowed/hidden until `umount /dir` is performed (where shadowed or hidden dirs/files are visible again).  I don't know wine very well, but suspect i'd be using that in your position (*and don't forget `dosbox` as it's really useful for that era games*)